# How to unlock IdeaPad Y400 HDD without its original motherboard?

Tags: hard-drive, security, bios, passwords

I locked an HDD of a Lenovo Ideapad Y400 laptop with its BIOS which was later unusable. Although the HDD was removed, but failure of unlocking it with disk tools and results of searches through the web both suggest that the Y400's motherboard may have its own method of locking its HDD.

That is, the motherboard may encrypt the password that user type in and then lock the HDD with encrypted password, unlike common motherboards locking the HDD with typed password directly.

Therefore, I cannot unlock the drive with the other motherboard of my older laptop, nor with disk tools. However I indeed remember the password, so I would be grateful for any methods or tools to unlock it.

Please note that I locked the HDD by entering the security page of the Y400 BIOS and setting the user password. If I'm correct, master password shown in the security page should be the one locks BIOS, while user password locks HDD. There's no something like HDD Master Password or HDD User Password shown on the page.
I have contacted lenovo’s official support from local store, USA website and website in my country. The result is that lenovo doesn’t have ideas neither...

Comment: I'd contact Lenovo directly & ask them. If anyone can do it, they can.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have contacted lenovo, see update of the question :)